# Simplifying Matrix UI Approach

Tags: usability, gui-design, design-patterns, interface, responsive-design

I have a current design which is in matrix form where **columns and rows can be added** and value is added. Is there any other solution for this other than using matrix. I dont want to use the matrix format because when used in matrix format the data will be squeezed when viewed in tablet.

I need other solution other than matrix approach.

PS this is old UI and i need to re do it.
[image]

Comment: The request for a redesign is out of the scope of this site. Can you provide more context and edit the question so that it asks for one specific answer?

Comment: I think the problem here is that you're trying to go straight to the UI rather than actually solving the issues, thus you're basically looking for a different aesthetic to replicate the same problems. This screen alone has a lot of issues, so it's easy to see you'll have a hard time making this work, simply because this screen isn't well thought out. I won't do your work, but try starting with this: **what is this for, and what is the most important data you need, and why?** Then you'll probably have 50% of the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple UI for construction time tracking. You should do some light UXR, at the very least do a Competitive Analysis for similar apps and a Heuristic Evaluation on your own interface.

Like @Devin mentioned you'll want to outline all the context for what you need and want before you start trying to update the UI.